# WSO2 - Identity server 6.1.0 - Self registration - No internal crypto providers available error

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When following the self registration tutorial under `WSO2 documentation` website, I am facing an `error` when calling the self registration API.

The error is:

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while encrypting the Credential for User Name XXXX
at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.workflow.userstore.UserStoreActionListener.doPreAddUser(UserStoreActionListener.java:125)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4913)
... 68 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.identity.workflow.mgt.exception.WorkflowException: Error while 
encrypting the Credential for User Name XXXX
at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.workflow.userstore.AddUserWFRequestHandler.startAddUserFlow(AddUserWFRequestHandler.java:121)
at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.workflow.userstore.UserStoreActionListener.doPreAddUser(UserStoreActionListener.java:119)
... 69 more
 Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoException: An error occurred while encrypting data.
at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.encrypt(CryptoUtil.java:146)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.encrypt(CryptoUtil.java:160)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.encryptAndBase64Encode(CryptoUtil.java:242)
at 
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.workflow.userstore.AddUserWFRequestHandler.startAddUserFlow(AddUserWFRequestHandler.java:119)
... 70 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.crypto.api.CryptoException: No internal crypto providers 
available. Correctly register a service implementation of 'interface 
org.wso2.carbon.crypto.api.InternalCryptoProvider' as an OSGi service
at 
 org.wso2.carbon.crypto.impl.DefaultCryptoService.encrypt(DefaultCryptoService.java:539)
at org.wso2.carbon.core.util.CryptoUtil.encrypt(CryptoUtil.java:144)
... 73 more
```

How to fix it and what is an `OSGi`? i tried to add a `secret key` to deployment.toml but it did not solve the issue.

Comment: WSO2 Identity Server is missing the necessary cryptographic providers to perform encryption. Make sure that the required crypto providers are properly registered as OSGi services. Double-check the configurations related to cryptographic providers in the deployment.toml file.

Comment: Do you mean the below?

# The KeyStore which is used for encrypting/decrypting internal data. By default the primary keystore is used as the internal keystore.

#[keystore.internal]
#file_name = "$ref{keystore.primary.file_name}"
#type = "$ref{keystore.primary.type}"
#password = "$ref{keystore.primary.password}"
#alias = "$ref{keystore.primary.alias}"
#key_password = "$ref{keystore.primary.key_password}"

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, the actual values (file_name, type, password, alias, key_password) should be provided instead of using the placeholders like "$ref{keystore.primary.file_name}". You need to replace these placeholders with the actual values of the KeyStore file, type, password, alias, and key password.

Comment: I added the following (same values as in carbon.xml). and still same issue:

#[keystore.internal]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "JKS"
password = "wso2carbon"
alias = "wso2carbon"
key_password = "wso2carbon"

Comment: it turned out that i had the same configuration twice under the toml file and one of them was pointing to the full jks path which was wrong, it should only contain the jks file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: add to deployment.toml the following (same as the configured details under carbon.xml but do not put the filepath of jks file only its name.

```
[keystore.internal]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
type = "JKS"
password = "wso2carbon"
alias = "wso2carbon"
key_password = "wso2carbon"
```